# "Clod" vs. "chunk" vs. "lump"

Tags: differences, nouns

Are there usage differences between *clod, chunk,* and *lump*? Are they interchangeable?

For example, is it better to use *lump* or *clod* for wood?

Comment: It's usually a "lump of coal" and a "clod of earth". Never heard of "chuk", but it is a romanization for a Cantonese word. No synonyms are 100% interchangeable, but in some contexts they may be. It all depends upon the sentence: context is all.

Comment: Thank you Bill, but I misspelled chuk, I actually meant chunk.

Comment: Wood comes in sticks, twigs, logs, boards, panels, even scraps — but seldom in lumps and never in clods.

Comment: How was this piece of wood formed? If you're in the forest, wood usually comes in the form of sticks, twigs, branches, logs. You could say "block of wood" if it was sawn from a larger piece and is roughly rectangularly shaped, especially if you're planning on making something out of it. If it's left over from a construction project, you would call it a "scrap of wood" or a "chip of wood", depending on how large it is. If it's a funny shape that grew that way in the tree, you could call it a "knot of wood", or it might be a "burl". Or you could say "piece of wood" to include everything above.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the differences between the words:

- "A clod of ***_*____**" is usually used for a congealed mass of some sort.
- "A chunk of ***_*____**" carries the connotation that the object is a fragment of a larger whole.
- "A lump of ***_*____**" is more broad and can be used to describe any irregularly shaped mass.

Comment: The problem with saying that "a cord of wood is the correct term here" is that it's far too specific. If the OP meant a "chunk of wood" -- and I think you're right about that -- then "a cord of wood" is most certainly incorrect. _Lump, chunk_, and _clod_ all mean a "broken piece of something larger", not a precise amount of anything, but a "cord of wood" is a precise amount.

Comment: A *cord* of wood is a [specific quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cord_(unit)). I think a *piece* of wood would come closer to what OP is asking about.

Comment: @BillFranke You're right about the usage of "cord", I've edited my answer. As far as `lump, chunk, and clod` all meaning a broken piece of something larger, I'm not so sure. A clod of dirt isn't a piece of something larger so much as it is something larger made of small pieces.

Comment: Would anyone explain what does OP stands for?

Comment: *Wood*, now I think of it, is tricky. The word itself implies a worked piece — rough-hewn, perhaps, but nonetheless detached from the original tree. Depending on the origin of the *piece* it might be a *chip* (an incidental byproduct of felling) or a *log* (a sawn or hewn length, otherwise unshaped) or a *scrap* (an incidental byproduct of woodworking*). But I find it difficult to imagine circumstances in which a *chunk* or *lump* of wood would come to hand.

Comment: @Patrick Can't tell if you're being sarcastic, but it is commonly used as an acronym for "Original Poster"

Comment: I would perhaps say that a chunk of wood rolled off the grate in my fireplace but I would never say clod or lump for wood. It just doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Asad: MW3UDE: "2 a : a lump or mass especially of earth, turf, or clay  b : SOIL, GROUND, EARTH; also : _a spot of earth or turf_". Although soil, earth, and ground are composed of smaller pieces only loosely bound and easily unbound from each other, everything is composed of myriad smaller pieces bound together and more or less easily unbound. A clod of earth isn't all the earth beneath your feet. A [divot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divot?show=0&t=1354373187) "2 a : a lump or mass especially of earth, turf, or clay  b : SOIL, GROUND, EARTH; also : _a spot of earth or turf_".

Comment: But you do say a *lump of charcoal* which is really just wood in a different form.

Comment: @Jim Everything in the universe is just hydrogen in a different form, but that doesn't have any bearing on the terminology we use for it. There is a meaningful distinction to be made between charcoal and wood.

Comment: @Asad- How do you mean?